# Moving SharePoint databases to a new Server

Tags: sql-server

I followed instructions from the [Move All Databases (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725.aspx) article.

I have a SQL alias set up on the original database server and the new database server.  I can connect to the old server from the new server via SQL Server Management studio. The configuration in SQL Server Configuration Manager on both servers is as
 follows:

**Alias**
sqlAlias TCP/IP Oldserver

**Client Protocols**
TCP/IP Enabled

Named Pipes Enabled

**SQL Server Services**

**Service**  **Running**  **Automatic**  **Log On As**

SQL Server Browser  Yes Yes  DOMAIN\SQLservice

SQL Server  Yes Yes  DOMAIN\SQLservice

SQL Server Agent  Yes Yes  DOMAIN\SQLservice

When I change both servers configuration by changing the alias to the new server, I cannot connect to the new server from the old server.  All server security logins match in SQL Server Management Studio. I am able to ping the new server from the old server using both the IP and the SQL alias. What am I missing?

Comment: Checked your firewalls for Ports?? Are you using standard ports (1433) or others?

Comment: It was the firewall.  If you answer the question, I'll mark your post as the answer.

Comment: Done, thank you too for getting back with the final resolution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you check your Firewall ports on the servers that require communications among them, or even better disable firewall while testing.